# timeout command in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am writing a GUI app in Python using tkinter for WiFi hacking. I'm having trouble with the command:

```
timeout 5s sudo airodump-ng {interface}mon
```

In my Linux terminal, I enter the following commands:

```
service network-manager stop
sudo airmon-ng check kill
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Then, to see all networks, I use the command

```
sudo airodump-ng start wlan0mon
```

However, I only want to see the output for 5 seconds as I cannot output the command in real-time in GUI app. The command

```
timeout 5s yes a
```

works properly for 5 seconds, but the command

```
timeout 5s sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

doesn't stop executing after 5 seconds.

I have tried using the command

```
timeout 5s sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

to see all networks for 5 seconds in your GUI app. However, this command did not stop executing after 5 seconds as expected.

Comment: I would try to play with signals that timeout sends to terminate. Either change the sent signal using  --signal or use just invoke with  --kill-after=5s.

Comment: Also, I think you cannot stop from the userspace the command running under root. You need to run your timeout also with sudo.

Comment: put the timeout under the sudo command

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.se] rather than Stack Overflow insofar as it's more about tool usage than software development.

Comment: (And after you've fixed your order-ofr-operations to do the `sudo` _before_ the `timeout`, a lot of the remaining question depends on whether your command is self-daemonizing; if it is, it'll escape `timeout` -- though for a lot of GUI tools you can just turn that feature off via a command-line option)